# React Native app working correct when test but APK isn't work correct

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm coding my website app with react-native. When app open, I want to show a splash screen as LoadingScreen (my custom component). I did and it works but when I export an apk, it works but not correct. LoadingScreen comp. is not shown. App return only a blank View with white background but I want to show this LoadingScreen component when opening.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar, Platform, BackHandler, View } from 'react-native';
import LoadingScreen from './LoadingScreen';
import AppStyle from './AppStyle';
import BannerAds from './BannerAds';
import InterstitialAds from './InterstitialAds';
import { AdEventType } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import Snackbar from 'react-native-snackbar';
import { OneSignal } from 'react-native-onesignal';


const MyWebView = () => {

  OneSignal.initialize("MY_OneSignal_KEY");
  OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(true);

  const webviewRef = useRef(null);
  const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState('https://www.rafhane.com/?m=1');
  const [showLoadingScreen, setShowLoadingScreen] = useState(true);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  let ilkHata = false;

  const openStatusBar = () => {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true);
  };


  const configureStatusBar = () => {
    StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('white');
    StatusBar.setHidden(false);


    if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 23) {
      StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content');
    } else {
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#999999');
    }
  };

  const adLoadedListener = () => {
    InterstitialAds.addAdEventListener(AdEventType.LOADED, () => {
      setLoaded(true);

    });
  };

  const netKontrol = () => {
    NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      if (state.isConnected) {
        if (ilkHata) {
          webviewRef.current.reload();
          setShowLoadingScreen(false);
          ilkHata = false;
          openStatusBar();
          configureStatusBar();
        }
        Snackbar.dismiss();
      } else {
        ilkHata = true;
        setShowLoadingScreen(true);
        openStatusBar();
        Snackbar.show({
          text: 'Bağlantınızı kontrol edin',
          duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE,
          backgroundColor: '#1d1d1d',
          action: {
            text: 'Tamam',
            textColor: '#f08167',
            onPress: () => { },
          },
        });
      }
    })
  };

  useState(() => {
    openStatusBar();
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    netKontrol();
    adLoadedListener();
    InterstitialAds.load();

    const handleBackButton = () => {
      if (currentUrl !== 'https://www.rafhane.com/?m=1') {
        webviewRef.current.goBack();
      } else {
        BackHandler.exitApp();
      }
      return true;
    };

    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);

    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);
    };
  }, [currentUrl]);

  const onNavigationStateChange = (navState) => {
    setCurrentUrl(navState.url);
  };



  const onWebViewLoad = () => {
    const script = `
      var element1 = document.getElementById('RafhaneBilgiAlt');
      if (element1) {
        element1.style.display = 'none';
      }

      var element2 = document.getElementById('copyright-rafhane');
      if (element2) {
        element2.style.display = 'none';
      }

      var element3 = document.getElementById('Label1');
      if (element3) {
        element3.style.display = 'none';
      }

      var element4 = document.getElementsByClassName('google-auto-placed');
      for (var i = 0; i < element4.length; i++) {
        element4[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    `;

    webviewRef.current.injectJavaScript(script);
  };

  return (
    <View style={AppStyle.container}>
      {showLoadingScreen && <LoadingScreen />}
      
      <SafeAreaView style={AppStyle.containerWV}>
        <WebView
          onError={() => {
            setShowLoadingScreen(true)
          }}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          source={{ uri: currentUrl }}
          onLoad={onWebViewLoad}
          ref={webviewRef}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
          onLoadEnd={() => {
            setShowLoadingScreen(false);
            if (loaded) {
              configureStatusBar();
              InterstitialAds.show();
              InterstitialAds.removeAllListeners();
              setLoaded(false);
            }
          }}
        />
        {!showLoadingScreen && <BannerAds />}
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyWebView;
```

**AppStyle.js**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default AppStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  containerWV: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  }
});
```

**LoadingScreen.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, Animated, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import styles from './LoadingScreenStyles';

const LoadingScreen = () => {
  const containerOpacity = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(containerOpacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ImageBackground style={styles.containerBG} source={require('../assets/bg.png')}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.container, { opacity: containerOpacity }]}
      >
        <View style={styles.containerLogo}>
          <Animated.Image
            style={styles.logo}
            source={require('../assets/rafhane.png')}
          />
          <Image style={styles.logoImg} source={require('../assets/text.png')} />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>www.rafhane.com</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textDescription}>v1.9.23</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

export default LoadingScreen;
```

**LoadingScreenStyles.js**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerBG: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 2,
    },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    },
  containerLogo: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  logoImg: {
    width: 100,
    height: 60,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 11,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
  textDescription: {
    fontSize: 10,
    color: '#ffffff',
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

**index.js (For ./LoadingScreen)**

```
export {default} from './LoadingScreen';
```